# Stopping a child control invalidating a parent control

Tags: .net, winforms, gdi+, gdi, onpaint

I am making a winforms designer control. The move/resize boxes are essentially `pictureboxes` added  as child controls to a parent `picturebox` control (call it 'Canvas'). All the actual drawing is done in the 'Canvas' pictureboxe's `OnPaint` Event, using the child pictureboxes for the locations and sizes. This is done via a loop, so all images/text gets drawn in one OnPaint event.

The problem is that each child control invalidates the parent 'Canvas' control, thus the same images/text get drawn repeatedly rather than just once. So, 5 child pictureboxes, Canvas gets redrawn 5 times....

The pictureboxes *have* to be child controls. Is there any way to stop these child controls automatically invalidating their parent control?

Comment: Please, show us the relevant code.

Comment: Well the code is 494 lines for the child controls and 515 lines for the manager method that draws the Canvas - do you want that? Can this really not be answered in theory?

Comment: An idea of what this *canvas* is and how it handle graphic buffering is needed. Is it a Custom Control? At least a description of what actions these child Controls perform. Maybe you just need empty containers that just have the resizing handles. Or send `WM_SETREDRAW` with WParam set to `false` to the Parent. Hard to say if nothing is known about the functionality of these Controls.

Comment: Fair point. I'm trying to recreate it as a simple case. After a day banging my head against a brick wall on this one, think I need to come back to it later.. thanks again, Jimi ;)

Comment: Sure. If you want to make a test, replace the Parent PictureBox with a UserControl, which is also double buffered and supports semi-transparent colors. Try to remove `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` from the class styles. The child Controls, if transparent or semi-transparent can force a double-buffered parent to `Invalidate()` only their bounds, or nothing if these Controls handle the painting of the background themselves.